# Question about topology and paths (and continuity)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, curves

Let $U$ be an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $x\in U$ and a sequence $x_n\to x$

> Prove that there exists a path $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to U$ s.t:
>
> $\gamma \ is\  C^2$
>
> $\gamma(0)=x$
>
> $\gamma'(0)\ne 0$
>
> and $\gamma(-\delta,\delta)$ contains $x_n$ for infinitely many $n$  for every $0<\delta<\epsilon$

So I understand the last condition would come from the fact that $\gamma$ is continuous and that $x_n\to x$ because $\gamma(-\delta,\delta)$ is mapped to an open neighbourhood of x and that means that starting from some N, it will contain all of $x_n$ for $n>N$

The rest though, I really don't know how to prove..

Any help?

Comment: One small point for the last condition:  It should probably be something like $\gamma(-\delta,\delta)$ contains $x_n$ for infinitely many $n$.  Otherwise we can consider $x_n =x$ for all $n$, in which case there aren't infinitely many points to work with.